# How to set the Ticks on BodePlot?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8

I can't seem to be able to change the Ticks on BodePlot in Mathematica 8.

```
Clear[z]
hz = z/(z - 0.4) (*make up some transfer function *)
ts = 1;
tf = TransferFunctionModel[hz, z, SamplingPeriod -> ts];
scale = {{"Linear", "dB"}, Automatic};

BodePlot[tf,
 PlotRange -> Automatic,
 ImageSize -> 300,
 ScalingFunctions -> scale,
 Ticks -> {{{0, Pi/4, Pi/2, 3/4 Pi, Pi}, Automatic}, Automatic}
 ]
```

According to documentation, all Plot options can be used for BodePlot.

Notice the format for Ticks for BodePlot is supplied as 2 lists not one as normal plots, as there are 2 plots generated. In the above, I am trying to change the x-axis ticks for the first plot (the magnitude plot).

The question is: How to change Ticks on BodePlot? Am I making an error in the above call?

thanks

### EDIT 1

Now using FrameTicks, and I found a really strange behavior. If I use Automatic for any of the ticks for the right or top sides of the frame, I get kernel errors in the console. Here is an example

```
Clear[z]
hz = z/(z - 0.4)
tf = TransferFunctionModel[hz, z, SamplingPeriod -> 1];

BodePlot[tf,
 FrameTicks -> 
     {
     {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, None}}, 
     {{Automatic, None}, {Automatic, None}}
     }
 ]
```

The above gives kernel error messages on the console. The strange thing, if I run the same command again, I do not see the errors again on the console.

Change the above to the following, and the errors go away:

```
Clear[z]
hz = z/(z - 0.4)
tf = TransferFunctionModel[hz, z, SamplingPeriod -> 1];

BodePlot[tf,
 FrameTicks -> 
    {
     {{Automatic, None}, {Automatic, None}}, 
     {{Automatic, None}, {Automatic, None}}
    }
 ]
```

And when I use this, I do not get errors:

```
Clear[z]
hz = z/(z - 0.4)
tf = TransferFunctionModel[hz, z, SamplingPeriod -> 1];

BodePlot[tf,
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}
 ]
```

So, it seems using Automatic instead of None for the right side and the top side in FrameTicks causes a problem for BodePlot. I thought automatic was a safe value to use when in doubt, but not in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BodePlot` returns pictures with `Frames`, rather than `Axes`, so use `FrameTicks` rather than `Ticks`.

Comment: +1, that is it. I got blindsided by the documenation saying this: "BodePlot has the same options as Plot", so I did not think of trying Frame options, but was looking at Plot options only. Thanks!

Comment: `Frame` and `FrameTicks` are `Plot` options.  They just aren't used by default.

Comment: Do you know why some functions can detect an invalid option but others do not? I use the notebook interface, and I see that when I try to use an option to a function which it does not handle, then the option name font turns to red olor, telling one this option is not supported or not valid in that location. But in this case, since Ticks is not supported by BodePlot, this did not happen. I think some Mathematica functions need to do better job in detecting invalid options being passed to them.